# Server redirected too many times (20)

Tags: java, http

Здравствуйте.
Получаю ошибку "Server redirected too many  times (20)" и не понимаю,что делать.Вроде редиректы выключил, а получить ответ от сервера всё равно не могу.В теории сервер должен вернуть 302 редирект и всё должно быть ок,но так как куку я не могу принять так,как я делаю это обычно - ничего не выходит.А именно,я вырезаю куку из ответа сервера и потом её использую,можете кидать ссаными тряпками.

Вот код:

```
String resp = sendRequest("http://pumpyt.com/", "");


...


public static String sendRequest(String url, String cookie) {
    int responseCode = 0;
    String inputLine = "";
    String buf = "";
    String resp = "";
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        // add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("Host",
                "pumpyt.com");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language",
                "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        // con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine + "\n");
        }
        in.close();
        resp = response.toString();
        resp = new String(resp.getBytes("Cp1251"), "UTF-8");
        Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            buf += entry.getKey() + entry.getValue() + "\n";
        }

        buf += "\n";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        ConsoleWrite("Request error.");
    }
    return buf + resp;
}
```

Лог:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
Request error.
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at thrd.sendRequest(thrd.java:71)
at thrd.getCookies(thrd.java:44)
at main.main(main.java:15)
```

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Вот вроде твой ответ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746140/infinite-redirect-loop-in-http-request

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась постановкой

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

Перед объявлением

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```